# How to change pairs in a map?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, key-value

I have a `Map<Integer, Character> alphabetMap`, which contains links from number to alphabet.

For example: `[1: 'A', 2: 'B', ... , 26: 'Z']`

I have a rotate() method, which should put the entries with changing links

After first using of the method my map should be `[1: 'Z', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', ... , 26: 'Y']`

Here is my current realisation:

```
public void rotate() {
    final Map<Integer, Character> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    alphabetMap.forEach((key, value) -> tempMap.put(key == 26 ? 1 : key + 1, value));
    alphabetMap = tempMap;
}
```

Is there any another way/algorhitm to "rotate" my entries quicker?

Comment: Since the keys are in numerical order, I suggest using an array or a list intsead of a map.

Answer (score 3):

For "faster" rotation the map could be replaced with a list and then method [`Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) could be used for this purpose.  Then the list elements may be accessed by index in range `[0..25]`.

Or a small wrapper class may be implemented:

```java
static class MyCharMap {
    private List<Character> chars = IntStream
        .rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
        .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    public void rotate() {
        Collections.rotate(chars, 1);
    }
    
    public Character get(Integer i) {
        assert(1 <= i && i <= 26);
        return chars.get(i - 1);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4 * chars.size() + 2);
        sb.append('{');
        for (int i = 0, n = chars.size(); i < n; i++) {
            if (i > 0) sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(i + 1).append(':').append(chars.get(i));
        }
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
MyCharMap chars = new MyCharMap();
        
chars.rotate();
chars.rotate();
System.out.println(chars);
System.out.println(chars.get(1));
```

Output:

```
{1:Y, 2:Z, 3:A, 4:B, 5:C, 6:D, 7:E, 8:F, 9:G, 10:H, 11:I, 12:J, 13:K, 14:L, 15:M, 16:N, 17:O, 18:P, 19:Q, 20:R, 21:S, 22:T, 23:U, 24:V, 25:W, 26:X}
Y
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your approach if using a map. But since rotations must be relative to some order and maps are unordered, you may want to use a List as suggested by [Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682686/1552534).

Here is another alternative using maps.  It permits left or right rotation by any amount (based on the sign) for a supplied map that has sequential integer keys starting at 1.  It also adjusts for counts exceeding the size by using the `remainder operator`. For left or right rotation offsets are simply calculated and the map altered and returned for subsequent processing.

```
BiFunction<Map<Integer, Character>, Integer, Map<Integer, Character>> rotate =
        (mp, cnt) -> {
            int size = mp.values().size();
            int count = cnt < 0 ? size + (cnt % size) - 1 :
                    cnt - 1;
            return mp.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                            (e.getKey() + count) % size + 1,
                            e.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                            e -> e.getValue()));
        };

System.out.println(map);     // original map - 10 elements
map = rotate.apply(map,1);   // right one - starting at J
System.out.println(map);        
map = rotate.apply(map,-2);  // left two, skipping A, going to B
System.out.println(map);
map = rotate.apply(map, -21);// Essentially left one going to C
System.out.println(map);
map = rotate.apply(map, 22); // Essentially right two going to A
System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 6=F, 7=G, 8=H, 9=I, 10=J}
{1=J, 2=A, 3=B, 4=C, 5=D, 6=E, 7=F, 8=G, 9=H, 10=I}
{1=B, 2=C, 3=D, 4=E, 5=F, 6=G, 7=H, 8=I, 9=J, 10=A}
{1=C, 2=D, 3=E, 4=F, 5=G, 6=H, 7=I, 8=J, 9=A, 10=B}
{1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 6=F, 7=G, 8=H, 9=I, 10=J}
```

The lambda version could easily be replaced by a regular method that takes a single rotate value and works on a fixed map.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Alex Rudenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682686/7376590), you can create a custom map that uses  [Collections.rotate(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) behind the scenes.

##### Custom map:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class MyMap {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final Map<Integer, ?> initMap;
    private final List<?> list;
    private Map<Integer, ?> rotatedMap;

    public MyMap(List<?> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.initMap = setMap(this.list);
        this.rotatedMap = cloneMap(this.initMap);
    }

    private Map<Integer, ?> setMap(List<?> list) {
        return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(list::get, Function.identity()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .peek(e -> e.setValue(e.getValue() + 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
    }

    private Map<Integer, ?> cloneMap(Map<Integer, ?> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }

    public Map<Integer, ?> get() {
        counter = 0;
        return rotatedMap;
    }

    public MyMap reset() {
        counter = 0;
        this.rotatedMap = cloneMap(this.initMap);
        return this;

    }

    public MyMap rotate() {
        return rotateMap(++counter);
    }

    public MyMap rotate(int distance) {
        return rotateMap(distance);
    }

    private List<?> cloneList(List<?> list) {
        return list.stream().map(e -> e).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private MyMap rotateMap(int distance) {
        List<?> list = cloneList(this.list);
        Collections.rotate(list, distance);
        this.rotatedMap = setMap(list);
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return rotatedMap.toString();
    }
}
```

##### Example 1 (Rotate twice, Reset rotation, Rotate twice.):

```java
// Rotate twice, Reset rotation, Rotate twice.
MyMap myCharMap1 = new MyMap(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
System.out.println(myCharMap1
        .rotate(2)
        .reset()
        .rotate().rotate()
        .get()); // {1=C, 2=D, 3=A, 4=B}
```

##### Example 2 (Rotate thrice. Can rotate a String list):

```java
//Rotate thrice.
MyMap myMap = new MyMap(Arrays.asList("Peter", "James", "Sam", "Tiffany", "Mathew"));
System.out.println(myMap.rotate(3).get()); // {1=Sam, 2=Tiffany, 3=Mathew, 4=Peter, 5=James}
```

##### Example 3 (Rotate once. Can rotate a numeric list as well):

```java
// Rotate once. Can rotate a numeric list as well.
MyMap myDigitMap3 = new MyMap(Arrays.asList(38, 56, 98, 160));
System.out.println(myDigitMap3.rotate(1).get()); // {1=160, 2=38, 3=56, 4=98}
```

##### Example 4 (Can accept negative rotations):

```java
//Can accept negative rotations.
MyMap myMap = new MyMap(Arrays.asList("Peter", "James", "Sam", "Tiffany", "Mathew"));
System.out.println(myMap.rotate(-3).get()); // {1=Tiffany, 2=Mathew, 3=Peter, 4=James, 5=Sam}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @code-apprentice in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681781/how-to-change-pairs-in-a-map#comment124958238_70681781)

> Since the keys are in numerical order, I suggest using an array or a
> list instead of a map.

If in case you still want to return a map, you could use the [`Collections.rotate(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) method in conjunction with reconstructing the expected map.

```java
BiFunction<List<?>, Integer, Map<Integer, ?>> rotate =
        (list, distance) -> {

            Function<List<?>, Map<Integer, ?>> setMap = (arrayList) -> IntStream.range(0, arrayList.size())
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(arrayList::get, Function.identity()))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .peek(e -> e.setValue(e.getValue() + 1))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));

            Collections.rotate(list, distance);
            return setMap.apply(list);

        };

System.out.println(rotate.apply(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 1)); // {1=D, 2=A, 3=B, 4=C}
System.out.println(rotate.apply(Arrays.asList("Peter", "James", "Sam", "Tiffany", "Mathew"), -3)); // {1=Tiffany, 2=Mathew, 3=Peter, 4=James, 5=Sam}
```